# adb shell "Bus Error" while running sqlite3 file.db

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

I am unable to use "sqlite3" in my Asus Zenfone 5. Its rooted device and has sqlite3 in /system/xbin.
Whenever I run as root, for "sqlite3 file.db", It shows me following error.

```
Bus error
```

Its too time consuming to move the .db file to laptop and perform operation and move back there. 
Suggest something to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed now. It was due to two separate versions of adb installed. One through Ubuntu apt-get and one through Android SDK. I purged the apt one. All good now.
Technically: Packages were conflicting.