# Android: Unable get adb working from Black BeagleBone wireless on debian buster

Tags: android, linux, adb, beagleboneblack

As I said in the title I am unable get adb working. I am running the latest version of Debian from the official Beaglebone website. I installed `android-tools-adb` and `android-tools-fastboot` packages and when I run `adb devices`command I get:

```
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /tmp/adb.0.log
Server had pid: 1718
--- adb starting (pid 1718) ---
adb I 07-24 09:45:21  1718  1718 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 07-24 09:45:21  1718  1718 main.cpp:57] Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5
adb I 07-24 09:45:21  1718  1718 main.cpp:57] Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 07-24 09:45:21  1718  1718 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 07-24 09:45:21  1718  1718 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 07-24 09:45:21  1718  1718 adb_auth_host.cpp:262] User key '/root/.android/adbkey' does not exist...
adb I 07-24 09:45:21  1718  1718 adb_auth_host.cpp:109] generate_key(/root/.android/adbkey)...

* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

And the result from `adb nodaemon server` command:

```
adb I 07-24 09:47:13  1721  1721 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 07-24 09:47:13  1721  1721 adb_auth_host.cpp:262] User key '/root/.android/adbkey' does not exist...
adb I 07-24 09:47:13  1721  1721 adb_auth_host.cpp:109] generate_key(/root/.android/adbkey)...
Bus error
```

Adb clearly says to me `Bus error` but why? I mean even `lsusb` tells me that all is working fine:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 18d1:4ee7 Google Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And even more weird when I do the same things with the same cable same android device on a new fresh raspberry all is working fine as expected.

Here is the output from gdb:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6c6f27c in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/android/libcrypto.so.0
#1  0xb6c6f60e in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/android/libcrypto.so.0
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) disas
No function contains program counter for selected frame.
(gdb) info reg
r0             0x436408            4416520
r1             0x436408            4416520
r2             0x8                 8
r3             0x436490            4416656
r4             0x4364b0            4416688
r5             0xe                 14
r6             0xb6c6eba1          3066489761
r7             0xb6c6f5e1          3066492385
r8             0x43658c            4416908
r9             0xbeffce48          3204435528
r10            0xe                 14
r11            0xbeffd04c          3204436044
r12            0xbeffc7a8          3204433832
sp             0xbeffc7a8          0xbeffc7a8
lr             0xb6c6f60f          -1228474865
pc             0xb6c6f27c          0xb6c6f27c
cpsr           0x600d0030          1611464752
fpscr          0x60000000          1610612736
(gdb) disas $pc-0x80,$pc+0x80
Dump of assembler code from 0xb6c6f1fc to 0xb6c6f2fc:
   0xb6c6f1fc:  vand    q10, q10, q8
   0xb6c6f200:  vand    q11, q11, q8
   0xb6c6f204:  veor    q7, q7, q10
   0xb6c6f208:  vshl.s64    q10, q10, #4
   0xb6c6f20c:  veor    q3, q3, q11
   0xb6c6f210:  vshl.s64    q11, q11, #4
   0xb6c6f214:  veor    q1, q1, q10
   0xb6c6f218:  veor    q0, q0, q11
   0xb6c6f21c:  vldmia  r4, {d16-d17}
   0xb6c6f220:  veor    q4, q4, q8
   0xb6c6f224:  veor    q6, q6, q8
   0xb6c6f228:  veor    q3, q3, q8
   0xb6c6f22c:  veor    q7, q7, q8
   0xb6c6f230:  veor    q2, q2, q8
   0xb6c6f234:  veor    q5, q5, q8
   0xb6c6f238:  veor    q0, q0, q8
   0xb6c6f23c:  veor    q1, q1, q8
   0xb6c6f240:  bx  lr
   0xb6c6f242:  nop
   0xb6c6f244:  nop.w
   0xb6c6f248:  nop.w
   0xb6c6f24c:  nop.w
   0xb6c6f250:  subw    r6, pc, #3
   0xb6c6f254:  vld1.8  {d14-d15}, [r4]!
   0xb6c6f258:  sub.w   r6, r6, #1712   ; 0x6b0
   0xb6c6f25c:  vld1.8  {d30-d31}, [r4]!
   0xb6c6f260:  vmov.i8 q8, #1  ; 0x01
   0xb6c6f264:  vmov.i8 q9, #2  ; 0x02
   0xb6c6f268:  vmov.i8 q10, #4 ; 0x04
   0xb6c6f26c:  vmov.i8 q11, #8 ; 0x08
   0xb6c6f270:  vmov.i8 q12, #16    ; 0x10
   0xb6c6f274:  vmov.i8 q13, #32    ; 0x20
   0xb6c6f278:  vldmia  r6, {d28-d29}
=> 0xb6c6f27c:  vrev32.8    q7, q7
   0xb6c6f280:  vrev32.8    q15, q15
   0xb6c6f284:  sub.w   r5, r5, #1
   0xb6c6f288:  vstmia  r12!, {d14-d15}
   0xb6c6f28c:  b.n 0xb6c6f290
   0xb6c6f28e:  nop
   0xb6c6f290:  vtbl.8  d14, {d30-d31}, d28
   0xb6c6f294:  vtbl.8  d15, {d30-d31}, d29
   0xb6c6f298:  vmov.i8 q6, #64 ; 0x40
   0xb6c6f29c:  vmov.i8 q15, #128   ; 0x80
   0xb6c6f2a0:  vtst.8  q0, q7, q8
   0xb6c6f2a4:  vtst.8  q1, q7, q9
   0xb6c6f2a8:  vtst.8  q2, q7, q10
   0xb6c6f2ac:  vtst.8  q3, q7, q11
   0xb6c6f2b0:  vtst.8  q4, q7, q12
   0xb6c6f2b4:  vtst.8  q5, q7, q13
   0xb6c6f2b8:  vtst.8  q6, q7, q6
   0xb6c6f2bc:  vtst.8  q7, q7, q15
   0xb6c6f2c0:  vld1.8  {d30-d31}, [r4]!
   0xb6c6f2c4:  vmvn    q0, q0
   0xb6c6f2c8:  vmvn    q1, q1
   0xb6c6f2cc:  vmvn    q5, q5
   0xb6c6f2d0:  vmvn    q6, q6
   0xb6c6f2d4:  vrev32.8    q15, q15
   0xb6c6f2d8:  subs    r5, #1
   0xb6c6f2da:  vstmia  r12!, {d0-d15}
   0xb6c6f2de:  bne.n   0xb6c6f290
   0xb6c6f2e0:  vmov.i8 q7, #99 ; 0x63
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
   0xb6c6f2e4:  bx  lr
   0xb6c6f2e6:  nop
   0xb6c6f2e8:  nop.w
   0xb6c6f2ec:  nop.w
   0xb6c6f2f0:  nop.w
   0xb6c6f2f4:  nop.w
   0xb6c6f2f8:  nop.w
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disas $lr-0x80,$lr+0x80
Dump of assembler code from 0xb6c6f58f to 0xb6c6f68f:
   0xb6c6f58f:  strh    r0, [r0, #0]
   0xb6c6f591:  sub.w   r0, r0, #16
   0xb6c6f595:  mov r10, r1
   0xb6c6f597:  mov r1, r9
   0xb6c6f599:  mov r2, r3
   0xb6c6f59b:  vorr    q4, q15, q15
   0xb6c6f59f:  vorr    q5, q0, q0
   0xb6c6f5a3:  blx 0xb6c13bdc <AES_decrypt@plt+4>
   0xb6c6f5a7:  vld1.8  {d0-d1}, [r9]
   0xb6c6f5ab:  veor    q0, q0, q4
   0xb6c6f5af:  vorr    q15, q5, q5
   0xb6c6f5b3:  vst1.8  {d0-d1}, [r10]
   0xb6c6f5b7:  vmov.i32    q0, #0  ; 0x00000000
   0xb6c6f5bb:  vmov.i32    q1, #0  ; 0x00000000
   0xb6c6f5bf:  vstmia  sp!, {d0-d3}
   0xb6c6f5c3:  cmp sp, r9
   0xb6c6f5c5:  bne.n   0xb6c6f5be
   0xb6c6f5c7:  mov sp, r9
   0xb6c6f5c9:  add sp, #16
   0xb6c6f5cb:  vst1.8  {d30-d31}, [r8]
   0xb6c6f5cf:  vpop    {d8-d15}
   0xb6c6f5d3:  ldmia.w sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, pc}
   0xb6c6f5d7:  nop
   0xb6c6f5d9:  nop.w
   0xb6c6f5dd:  nop.w
   0xb6c6f5e1:  cmp r2, #8
   0xb6c6f5e3:  bcc.w   0xb6c6f780
   0xb6c6f5e7:  mov r12, sp
   0xb6c6f5e9:  stmdb   sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, lr}
   0xb6c6f5ed:  vpush   {d8-d15}
   0xb6c6f5f1:  ldr.w   r8, [r12]
   0xb6c6f5f5:  sub sp, #16
   0xb6c6f5f7:  mov r9, sp
   0xb6c6f5f9:  ldr.w   r10, [r3, #240] ; 0xf0
   0xb6c6f5fd:  sub.w   r12, sp, r10, lsl #7
   0xb6c6f601:  add.w   r12, r12, #96   ; 0x60
   0xb6c6f605:  mov r4, r3
   0xb6c6f607:  mov r5, r10
   0xb6c6f609:  mov sp, r12
   0xb6c6f60b:  bl  0xb6c6f250
   0xb6c6f60f:  veor    q7, q7, q15
   0xb6c6f613:  vstmia  r12, {d14-d15}
   0xb6c6f617:  vld1.8  {d0-d1}, [r8]
   0xb6c6f61b:  add.w   r8, r6, #16
   0xb6c6f61f:  vldmia  sp, {d8-d9}
   0xb6c6f623:  vmov.i32    q8, #1  ; 0x00000001
   0xb6c6f627:  veor    q9, q9, q9
   0xb6c6f62b:  vrev32.8    q0, q0
   0xb6c6f62f:  vext.8  q8, q9, q8, #4
   0xb6c6f633:  vrev32.8    q4, q4
   0xb6c6f637:  vadd.i32    q9, q8, q8
   0xb6c6f63b:  vstmia  sp, {d8-d9}
   0xb6c6f63f:  b.n 0xb6c6f640
   0xb6c6f641:  vadd.i32    q10, q8, q9
   0xb6c6f645:  vadd.i32    q1, q0, q8
   0xb6c6f649:  vadd.i32    q2, q0, q9
   0xb6c6f64d:  vadd.i32    q3, q0, q10
   0xb6c6f651:  vadd.i32    q4, q1, q10
   0xb6c6f655:  vadd.i32    q5, q2, q10
   0xb6c6f659:  vadd.i32    q6, q3, q10
   0xb6c6f65d:  vadd.i32    q7, q4, q10
```

Comment: Maybe `/root` is not writeable?

Comment: I not touched that I mean it is just a pure Debian with Android adb installed and I runned adb with sudo

Comment: Check whether it is writeable by `mkdir /root/.android` and `touch /root/.android/adbkey`. If it worked, remove it again by `rm /root/.android/adbkey`

Comment: I cannot now but I will Monday but I don't changed that so I dont think it is an issue

Comment: Maybe the root filesystem is read-only by default or something like that.

Comment: Ah this is not stupid I will try that monday 

Comment: Ok so i tried to ``touch /root/.android/adbkey`` and it is working just fine as expected so i dont think that it is an issue about permission. And there is no adbkey file generated by adb

Comment: Does the `adb` binary come from a third-party repository? You could run it via `gdb` to see where it crashes.

Comment: I dont added a third-party repository i just run``sudo apt-get install`` & ``sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb``. How do you show the stack with gdb ?

Comment: My gdb shows that: ```(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/adb devices
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
/* Usual log error from adb*/
[Inferior 1 (process 4680) exited with code 01]```

Comment: You can print the stack trace with `bt`. The `Bus error` indicates that `adb` crashes with an unusual memory error and this has probably nothing to do with USB.

Comment: Ok so i run ``gdb -args adb devices`` after i run ``r`` and when i run ``bt`` it tells me ``No stack.``

Comment: Try `handle SIGBUS stop` before. Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44140784/4730685)?

Comment: Ok so ``handle SIGBUS stop`` did nothing in gdb and i only installed ``android-tools-adb``through apt

Comment: Did you try it with the `adb nodaemon server` command? That appears to be the one that actually crashes. The other ones just terminate because they can't connect to the daemon because it crashed.

Comment: Ok so it give that : ```Thread 1 "adb" received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0xb6c6f27c in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/android/libcrypto.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6c6f27c in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/android/libcrypto.so.0
#1  0xb6c6f60e in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/android/libcrypto.so.0
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)```

Comment: That seems that it is coming from `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/android/libcrypto.so.0` but Why what does it means ?

Comment: Does that file belong to the `adb` package? Might be wrong compilation settings. Perhaps file a bug with Debian. In gdb after the crash, try `disas` and `info reg` and show the full output (edit the original post text).

Comment: I dont think that it is an issue with Debian because i said in the original post all is working fine on an raspberry pi 3 with exact same setup and ``/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/android/libcrypto.so.0`` is from ``android-libcrypto-utils`` package which is installed with android-tools-adb

Comment: The pi 3 has a more powerful Cortex-A53 processor in comparison to the BBB's Cortex-A8; an application that was erroneosly compiled to take advantage of the A53's capabilities could crash on the A8. And since compiling applications is the distribution's job, they might have done something wrong. However, without (possibly a lot of) more debugging, nothing is certain...

Comment: So you think that BeagleBone has a bug inside their distribution right ? I dont think i will do more debugging(time consuming) but do you know where can i make a bug report ?

Comment: It is a possibility. There Debian Bug Tracker is [here](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting). Please at least show the output of `disas $pc-0x80,$pc+0x80` and `disas $lr-0x80,$lr+0x80`.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Not going to lie I am a novice when it comes to linux but this allowed me to connect to my phone with adb. Hope it helps until buster is fixed.

From Link rk-zero commented on Jan 17, 2020:

> I know this is more a debian issue, but i use this device as my main
> and only computer, so adb not working and quitting with key not found
> was a big issue for me.

To fix it, add stretch as a source in `/etc/apt/sources.d/stretch.list`

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
```

then downgrade adb:

```
apt update && apt install adb=1:7.0.0+r33-1 android-libadb=1:7.0.0+r33-1 android-libbase=1:7.0.0+r33-1 android-liblog=1:7.0.0+r33-1 android-libcutils=1:7.0.0+r33-1
```

voila, adb works again.
Quote
https://github.com/SolidHal/PrawnOS/issues/143